# How to disable flask checking for too many connection attemps (Error 10054)?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm designing a simple judgment project. I have two kinds of files, one kind is player and the other is referee. you can look at them as below:

> player.py is just simple flask app which will do sth when its URL
>   called and response some data

and

> referee.py is going to use requests library to tell players app to
>   what to do and analyze their responses.

as you can guess, the referee app is going to call players app too much and it causes flask to terminate some of the connection with 10054 error, is there any way to config flask to stop blocking referee.py's requests?

P.N.
I add some delay with time.sleep() but sometimes flask works fine but most of the time, it blocked the requests ...

Comment: Flask, by itself, is not going to be able to handle many simultaneous requests at the same time. You need an http server for that, in which you will run flask. See this for example: https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html

Comment: @zvone, I'm really thankful for your reply, using WSGI make everything works fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @zvone comment, there's no straight way to handle this problem with flask itself. Most common tool for handling this problem, was using gunicorn as WSGI but as I was on windows, I use waitress library instead and player.py became as bellow:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
    waitress.serve(app, listen='0.0.0.0:5000')
```